# ANSI C - Text File: Modify Line?

Tags: c, file, text, ansi-c

I have this text file:

```
Line 1. "house"
Line 2. "dog"
Line 3. "mouse"
Line 4. "car"
...
```

I want to change Line 2. "dog" in new Line 2."cards"

how can I do?

thanks!

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: The usual method is to open your file for input and a new file for output. Then process the input file and create the new file as you see fit. After you close both files, delete the original input file and rename the output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program could like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000

int main()
{
  FILE * fp_src, *fp_dest;
  char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

  fp_src = fopen("PATH_TO_FILE\\test.txt", "r"); // This is the file to change
  if (fp_src == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  fp_dest = fopen("PATH_TO_FILE\\test.txt_temp", "w"); // This file will be created
  if (fp_dest == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


  while (fgets(line, 1000, fp_src) != NULL) {

    if (strncmp(line, "Line 2.", 7) == 0) {
      fputs("Line 2. \"cards\"\n", fp_dest);
      printf("Applied new content: %s", "Line 2. \"cards\"\n");
    }
    else {
      fputs(line, fp_dest);
      printf("Took original line: %s", line);
    }

  }

  fclose(fp_src);
  fclose(fp_dest);

  unlink("PATH_TO_FILE\\test.txt");
  rename("PATH_TO_FILE\\test.txt_temp", "PATH_TO_FILE\\test.txt");

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The following things you should consider when taking this solution into some production system:

- Does the maximum line length of 1000 staisfy your needs - maybe you want to come up with a solution that uses `malloc()` to dynamically allocate memory for one line
- You should take some random-filename-generator to generate the temporary file and make sure that it doesn't exist yet, so you don't overwrite an existing file
- With large files this approach is maybe not the best because you effectivly have your file-content twice in memory

Comment: I'd drop the `unlink`; POSIX `rename` already guarantees atomic replacement, so explicitly `unlink`ing first introduces a (brief) window in which the program could die, and the old file would be gone, with neither old nor new data in it. If you're on Windows, you'd skip `rename` (which violates POSIX by not doing atomic replacement) and use `MoveFileEx` with the `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` flag to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit disk files inline. You have to follow the process of:

- reading the file data to buffer, (`fopen()` -> `fread()/fgets()`)
- then delete old file, (`unlink()/remove()`)
- then modify the data in buffer,
- write back buffer to a new file, (`fwrite`)
- rename it to original file. (`rename()`)

Comment: @gda2it : I don't believe in providing working code. A code will solve the problem for OP, but he may choose not to look around/research for the usage of 'alien' functions (such as `unlink`), which will be not useful in future for him. He may come back here and ask same question again.

Comment: Typically, there's no need to delete the old file, and you *shouldn't* do so explicitly. Just read from one file, write to a new temporary file, and when you're done, atomically rename/replace the original file with the new one. By waiting until the new file is fully populated, you avoid (most of) the risk of losing/corrupting data; either the original file still exists (and is correct/complete), or it's been atomically replaced with the new file (which was correct/complete before the replace occurred).